# JavaScript how to splice in that case

Tags: javascript, splice

- the frontend fetches activities from the API
- users can write comments to an activity
- I want to fetch the comments after clicking on a button

The code generates 2 calls:

1. get the activities and store them in the variable activities.
2. get the commentCount from a different endpoint

   ```
       //get activities
       dsActivity.getActivities(query)
           .then(function (items) {
               var activities = items.plain();

               for (var i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {

                   //get totalComment count
                   dsActivity.getActivityCount(activities[i].id)
                       .then(function (result) {
                           var totalComments = result.plain();
                           activities = totalComments;
                       }.bind(this));

                   this.items.push(activities);
               }
               if (this.offset < items.meta.page_count) {
                   this.offset += 1;
               } else {
                   return;
               }
               this.busy = false;
           }.bind(this));
   ```

It's currently not possible to include this field in the activitiy endpoint of the api. That's the reason why I want to put them together by using JS.

**DATA STRUCTURE**

**var activities:**
here are the activities

{
  "text": "first activity",
  "privacy": null,
  "createdAt": {
    "date": "2015-10-27 00:16:24.000000",
    "timezone_type": 3,
    "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
  },
  "id": 1,
  "comments": {},
}

**var totalComments**
here is the commentCount

{
  "comments": {
    "total_items": 6
  }
}

- How can I put the following data structures together in one array?

Comment: You need to make it clear what data is being returned from the server. What does `items` look like?

Comment: Better, but you still don't include what you want the data to be. Are you just trying to set the value of `comments` in your activities to the value of `totalComments`?

Comment: @forgivenson: yes correct, I've tried to give more informations in my post here.

Answer (score 0):

`splice` is an array method. Since you are trying to add a value to an object, `splice` is useless to you in this case. (see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for info about how to use `splice`)

All you need to do is:

```
activities[i].comments = result.plain();
```

This will assign the value of `result.plain()` to the property `comments` in the object `activities[i]`.

Comment: I already tried this. I get the following error:

[Error] Cannot set property 'comments' of undefined

Comment: Then `activities[i]` is undefined. You need to track down why that is. Apparently, your `getActivities` method isn't returning what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Now it seems to work, but is there a way to wait to the callback before pushing the data to the array?

```
//get activities
dsActivity.getActivities(query)
    .then(function (activityRes) {
        var activities = activityRes.plain();
        for (var i = 0; i < activities.length - 1; i++) {
            //get totalComment count
            dsActivity.getActivityCount(activities[i].id)
                .then(function (result) {
                    console.log(result.plain());
                    activities[i].comments = result.plain();
                }.bind(activities[i]));
            this.items.push(activities[i]);
        }
        console.log(this.items);
        if (this.offset < 1) {
            this.offset += 1;
        } else {
            return;
        }
        this.busy = false;
    }.bind(this));
```

The following line is the problem, it doesn't wait until the result.plain() is populated:

```
activities[i].comments = result.plain();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add the commentCount as a property of the original data.
data.commentCount = count.commentCount;

```
//get activities
dsActivity.getActivities(query)
    .then(function (items) {
        //For every item returned from getActivities
        for (var i = 0; i < items.plain().length; i++) {
            //Get the current # of Comments from getActivityCount
            dsActivity.getActivityCount(items.plain()[i].id)
                .then(function (result) {
                    //Add the returned object to the original items
                    items.plain()[i].comments = (result.plain()).comments;
                }.bind(this));
        }
        if (this.offset < items.meta.page_count) {
            this.offset += 1;
        } else {
            return;
        }
        this.busy = false;
    }.bind(this));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbcevfub/) proving the code working using raw objects.

**Javascript in JSFiddle**:

```
var activities = { "text": "first activity", "privacy": null, "createdAt": { "date": "2015-10-27 00:16:24.000000", "timezone_type": 3, "timezone": "Europe/Berlin" }, "id": 1, "comments": {}, }

var totalComments = { "comments": { "total_items": 6 } }

activities.comments=totalComments.comments

//The console prints the full object
console.log(activities);

//Prints the comments saved in activities (Should be 6)
document.write(activities.comments.total_items);
```

Comment: I've tried Your proposal. Unfortunately, I have the commentCount just in the last array object. I need to set the commentCount for every single activitiy. It has overwrote the data.commentCount with every for iteration.

Comment: What data structures are returned with getActivities and getActivityCount?

Comment: getActivities: {text: "", createdAt: "", "comments: ""}
getActivitiyCount: {"comments": {"total_items": 6}}

I've changed them a couple of minutes ago to get  them easier together.

I need to get the "comments" from getActivitiyCount into getActivities "comment".

Comment: That data makes no sense with the code you have. Also, you have two different versions of your code. Please rewrite your question, including the actual code you are using, the data that is returned by your server calls, the output that your code currently produces, and what output you expect. Currently, your question is very confusing.

Comment: Does this fix your issue? I placed the code inside your 2nd callback

Comment: Also I'm not entirely sure what plain() does, I've never used that method and am unsure what libraries you are using. But if the data returned in a call back is a JS Object, plain() is not needed and if the data is returned as a string, you can use JSON.parse(items) to turn it into a JS Object.